# Is there a way to create very high aspect ratio images from movies?

Tags: image, animation

I am trying to process images of very high aspect ratio defects (on the order of 100:1) with Mathematica (perhaps using movies)?  I am trying to analyze long, thin, defects in coated film.  If I take a picture of a section of them, I can analyze the shape of the section using Insert>Picture>From File.  The problem is the sections look like:

[image]

I want to analyze the full length with the maximum resolution I can get.  I can capture a "panoramic" shot as a jpg, but the maximum ratio is only 4:1.  I would like to get more like 100:1 aspect ratio.  If I had a line scan camera, it would be simple, but I am hoping to capture a movie to and convert it to a high aspect image to analyze defects (essentially doing a line scan of the movie in Mathematica).  It seems like it should be simple, but I  have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Four questions and still you have not taken the **[tour]**?  It may help you understand what is more effective way of asking Take the [tour]! What is the input? An image File? Which format? You want to "analyse" it, How? Looking at it? Applying a function?  Is the problem about the display of the image or the way to programmatically extract information from it? What have you tried? Why exactly did that not work? Did you search for similar problems? Did you find something ? How is your question different from what you found? Don't make us guess. Please **[edit]** your question to improve it now

Comment: Surely just take a bunch of photos and use `ImageStitch`? Like this `ImageStitch[{{image1, image2, image3, image4, ...}}]` [It's in the documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0fq6nvx7zjd12-8cexab) and you only need a single row of images.

Answer (score 2):

I am using: https://ducklink-screen-capture.en.uptodown.com/windows to make a screen shot with an arbitrary aspect ratio. E.g.

[image]